# record multiple clicks as an array

Tags: local-storage

I am currently recording the click of an li and storing the contents of it with localStorage.

I have a quiz question with multiple choice answers, which currently stores what answer they have chosen, but overwrites it with whatever they clicked last if they change their mind.

This works great for single choice questions, but for questions where more than one answer is allowed this will not work.

What I need to do is to be able to record all the clicks and store them as an array.

Here is my existing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

<style type="text/css">

body{
    text-align: center;
}

#questions{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 802px;
    height: 602px;
}

/*look for any class that has the word slide in it*/
[class*="slide"]{
    padding: 20px;
    background: #666;
    width: 760px;
    height: 560px;
    border: 1px dashed #333;
}
[class*="slide"]:nth-child(odd){
    background: #999;
}

b{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="questions">
        <div class="slide1">
            <h1>What is h2o?</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>A Pencil</li>
                <li>Liquid water</li>
                <li>A mobile phone network</li>
                <li>Paper</li>
            </ul>
            <p>check</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide2">
            <h1>What is 2 + 2?</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
            <p>check</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide3">
            <h1>What is a whale?</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>A mammal</li>
                <li>A fish</li>
                <li>A bird</li>
                <li>A country</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slide4">
            <h1>What phone do you prefer?</h1>
        <ul>
                <li>iPhone 4s</li>
                <li>iPhone 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slide5">
            <h1>What is 5 + 5?</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>10</li>
                <li>7</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slide6">
            <h1>What is the capital city of England?</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>London</li>
                <li>Staines</li>
                <li>Bognor Regis</li>
                <li>Luton</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="slide7">
            <h1>What colour is a red phone box?</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Blue</li>
                <li>Red</li>
                <li>Pink</li>
                <li>Mauve</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b></b>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    /*
    //
    //  quiz storer and answer checker
    //  Author: Tjobbe Andrews
    //  v1.0, 13/02/2013
    //  - keeps a record in localStorage of the answers you chose, then checks them on an ad hoc basis
    //
    */

    //on clicking the answers in the li's..
    $("li").click(function(){
        //..create a variable called answer based on the content of that li..
        var answer = $(this).html();
        //..and create a variable called question based on the class of the parent div
        var question = $(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
        //then store the key value pair of question and answer
        localStorage.setItem(question, answer);
        //just makes sure that it's writing to the LS db
        $("b").html(localStorage.getItem(question));
    });

    //click the p tag to check what we've got stored for this div - ad hoc
    $('p').click(function(){
        var slideNumber = $(this).closest('div').attr('class');
        var answer = localStorage.getItem(slideNumber);
        if(answer !== "Liquid water"){
            alert('wrong');
        }
        else if(answer == "Liquid water"){
            alert("right");
        }
    });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't store an array in localStorage as is, but you can easily convert an array into a JSON string and store that instead. If your browser supports it, you can use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse. Otherwise, download a JSON library.

Comment: Thanks, I've read this elsewhere too. Problem is I don't know HOW to record multiple clicks or use stringify, just haven't found a simple enough explanation.

Comment: To use JSON stringify, you take an array, or other complex data, and just pass it to it. So given an array x, x=[1,2,3], you can do: s = JSON.stringify(x). Here is a MDN reference for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: As to your first question. If you have an event listener for clicks, you can use simple logic to determine if a user has already clicked on this question before. If they have an answer A picked and they just clicked B, then you simply create an array from those answers.